# MongoDB Shard Document Insertion

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I create a shard and the status seems to be good

```
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("58aefb3181741b40c635c327")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "repl1",  "host" : "repl1/prod-mongo-repl1:27017,prod-mongo-repl1:27018,prod-mongo-repl1:27019",  "state" : 1 }
    {  "_id" : "repl2",  "host" : "repl2/prod-mongo-repl2:27017,prod-mongo-repl2:27018,prod-mongo-repl2:27019",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
    "3.4.2" : 1
 autosplit:
    Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
        No recent migrations
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "mydatabase",  "primary" : "repl1",  "partitioned" : true }
        mydatabase.extract_purchases
            shard key: { "month" : 1, "year" : 1 }
            unique: false
            balancing: true
            chunks:
                repl1   1
            { "month" : { "$minKey" : 1 }, "year" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "month" : { "$maxKey" : 1 }, "year" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : repl1 Timestamp(1, 0)
```

But now, trying to insert or event just run a find command doesn't work, and I have this kind of message after a few seconds / minutes:

Trying:

```
db.extract_purchases.insert({year:2017, month:1})
```

The result is

```
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 82,
        "errmsg" : "no progress was made executing batch write op in mydatabase.extract_purchases after 5 rounds (0 ops completed in 6 rounds total)"
    }
})
```

I don't know what to do... I'm in a "mongos" shell

Thanks a lot by advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

We have a shard in production and I have never seen this error.

Can you check the **health of each replica set** (Config, repl1 & repl2) to make sure you have a primary on each ? (You'll have to connect directly to a member of each replica set to check that, you can't do it through mongos)

Can you also **check the logs of the primaries** (repl1 in particular since there is only 1 chunk for now) when you try to insert or read the data ?

Can you also try to write in an unsharded collection of the same database ? And of another database ?

Henri-Maxime (from Lille, someone sent me here...)

Comment: Hi! thanks for help: I can write in unsharded collection. The problem appear just after activating shard for a collection. I do have a Primary on each config, repl1 && repl2...

Comment: Hi, I reconfigure a full shard infra today, and the problem is the same... (Je peux te contacter? entre lillois?)

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to reach you but it doesn't seem to work ;)

Comment: I send you an email yesterday!! you didn't receive it?